# contourf() breaks for 2-d array of datetime objects as axis

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib`'s `contourf` function to display `z` data as function of `x` and `y`. I am able to use a `numpy` array of `datetime` objects as the x-axis if `x` and `y` are 1-d arrays. However, When I make my `x` and `y` arrays 2-dimensional, `contourf` breaks on 2-d array of `datetime` objects. Example follows:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([datetime(2012,12,12),datetime(2012,12,13),datetime(2012,12,14)])
y = np.arange(10)
z = np.random.random((10,3))

plt.contourf(x,y,z)
```

This example works and produces an expected result. However, if I do this:

```
x = np.tile(np.reshape(x,( 1,3)),(10,1))
y = np.tile(np.reshape(y,(10,1)),( 1,3))
```

so that `x`, `y`, and `z` are all of shape `(10,3)`, `contourf(x,y,z)` yields this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_2d_datetime.py", line 14, in <module>
    plt.contourf(x,y,z)
  File "/home/disk/mako/milan/epd/epd-7.3-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2206, in contourf
    ret = ax.contourf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/disk/mako/milan/epd/epd-7.3-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7322, in contourf
    return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/disk/mako/milan/epd/epd-7.3-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1106, in __init__
    ContourSet.__init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/disk/mako/milan/epd/epd-7.3-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 700, in __init__
    self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/disk/mako/milan/epd/epd-7.3-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1119, in _process_args
    x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/disk/mako/milan/epd/epd-7.3-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1166, in _contour_args
    x,y,z = self._check_xyz(args[:3], kwargs)
  File "/home/disk/mako/milan/epd/epd-7.3-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1194, in _check_xyz
    x = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float64)
  File "/home/disk/mako/milan/epd/epd-7.3-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 235, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

If I use a 2-d array of `matplotlib.dates.date2num()` values instead of `datetime` objects, `contourf()` works as expected.

Is there a remedy for the problem I am encountering? I am using Python `2.7.3` with matplotlib `1.1.0` on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: Is the remedy not to use date2num then? Is there a problem with that approach?

Comment: It works with mpl 1.2, so perhaps you can update.

Comment: I can replicate the issue with 1.2.0 on Windows. @IRO-bot: using x, y = np.meshgrid(x,y) is much easier then tiling+reshaping

Comment: @pelson `date2num` does not give me problems, as it's just a 2-d array of floats. 2-d arrays of `datetime` objects seem to be problematic.

Comment: @RutgerKassies Thanks for the `np.meshgrid` tip, I keep learning new things.